# ASP.NET MVC - Passing a parameter to my action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

```
    public ActionResult RenderMyThing(IList<String> strings)
    {
        return View("RenderMyView");
    }
```

How do I pass in strings?

```
        routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "RenderMyThing.aspx", new { controller = "My", action = "RenderMyThing" });
```

Is there a way I could pass in strings here?

Secondly, how does ASP.NET MVC know that action is my action, and controller is my controller. Like I saw this in samples, and it does work, but isn't it just an anonymous object with no type?

Comment: This should really be two separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the provenance of model binding: the framework needs to have some instruction as to how to turn a "request", which comes out of the routing context, query string, forms collection, etc., into the parameters that your action method wants.

The `DefaultModelBinder` will generate a list if it sees that you have multiple key-value pairs with the same key (and appropriately typed/convertible values) - for the details, [Phil wrote a good post about this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx):

If you need fancier binding requirements, you can implement a custom model binder and explicitly define how route values and the other bits get translated into objects (or collections of objects).